# "We need these shipments made as soon as possible." > Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

"We need these shipments made as soon as possible." > Is this sentence correct?

Someone who's American said it like that, so I asked someone who's Korean about this sentence, and he said it's not correct and it should be changed to "We need to make these shipments as soon as possible".  Is he right?

Comment: *We need it **done*** is a valid pattern.  You could say *We need these items **shipped** as soon as possible.*

Comment: Your Korean friend is not correct – either form is valid and grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

The customer says what he wishes *done*.

The shipper says what he has *to do*.

Customer ~= a person making a demand

Shipper ~= a person responding to a demand

Normally the *customer* would say this to the shipper:

> I need those items *shipped* ASAP.

or

> I need *you to ship* those items ASAP.

The foreman of the shipping company could say to the employees:

> We need *to ship* these items ASAP.

But it is not impossible for the foreman of the shipping company to say to the employees:

> We need these items shipped ASAP.

though I don't think that is as likely as the infinitive version ("We need to ship...") when spoken by the shipper.

The shipping foreman might say:

> The customer needs these items shipped ASAP.

or

> **I** need these items *shipped* ASAP.

in which case he is then making a demand of the employees in the same way that the customer has made a demand of the shipper.